# How to cache user credentials for asp.net mvc3 mobile application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have developed a mobile application using asp.net mvc3,html5,jquerymobile. I am authenticating the user using the ADFS authentication. Using IPAD or IPhone once the user is authenticated he is able to perform a download functionality in order to download an application. Now once the download functionality is completed when the user again tries to navigate back to the application he is prompted with the login window once again.

I need to stop the user from again entering the login credentials once again. So I thought of caching the user credentials will be good idea.

Can anyone help me to know how can we cache the user credential details in this case in order to prevent the user from entering the login credentials once again.

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro

Answer (score 1):

You could use persistent cookies. When authenticating simply pass true as second argument to the [`FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b.aspx) method. This will emit a cookie that will be stored on the client for the given timeout period that you specify in the `<forms>` of your web.config.